# Grails 3 - get rendered view from service

Tags: grails, grails3, grails3.2.0

I'm using Grails Views and want to store the JSON outputted from a rendered template in the database. I'm not trying to send the rendered template to the user, only to store it for later user. How can I get do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See section 2.9 at http://views.grails.org/1.1.2/#_the_jsontemplateengine.

```
Template t = templateEngine.resolveTemplate('/book/show')
def writable = t.make(book: new Book(title:"The Stand"))
def sw = new StringWriter()
writable.writeTo( sw )
```

Then you can do whatever you like with `sw`.

Comment: In case anyone runs into an exception: "grails.views.ViewException: Error rendering view: null", I resolved it by removing the response.status from the template.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the groovyPageRenderer in situations like this. See Page Rendering API section here: http://docs.grails.org/2.1.0/guide/introduction.html

```
class myService {
    PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer

    String renderTemplate(){
        return groovyPageRenderer.render([view: '/path/to/gsp', model:[key1:'val1', key2:'val2']])
    }
}
```

For me, this works great in the rare instances I want/need a service to generate HTML from a GSP.